# Is there a IRC Client which can use or emulate mIRC scripts

Tags: software-recommendation, compatibility, irc

I've used mIRC (Windows) for years, and have some custom scripts, written in mIRC's own scripting language.

Is there an Ubuntu/Linux IRC Client which will allow me to use my scripts *as-is*?

Failing that, is there a  "*functions a lot like mIRC*" Client available?

I've just tried Pidgin's IRC client, but it seems to be quite basic.
I couldn't see any way for it to tap into channel activity via scripts.

I don't want to use Wine... WineHQ reports it as having too many bugs for my liking, and anyhow, I try to avoid using Wine like I do Windows :)

Comment: Do not forget that Pidgin is a generalistic application, made to function with a wide variety of IM protocols - as such, IRC scripting is not the focus of Pidgin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Try irssi or XChat.

Comment: Thanks... I've subsequently read the mIRC site itself: It says: `Linux has quite a few native IRC clients, although none of them are quite like mIRC.` ... and it also said there are some *very similar* Clients for the Apple Mac (and named four of them).

Comment: Also consider weechat

Answer (score 3):

Konversation is the most similar to mIRC.  I used it for a bit, then xchat but now am solely using  irssi.  It is hands down the best route if you learn how to use it properly.

Once you have scripts/themes/plugins setup the way you want it feels so nice and much less cumbersome than the GUI based irc clients.

- [irssi documentation](http://irssi.org/documentation/tips) - irssi documentation and information from irssi site, good general info and base setup guides there.
- [irssi and screen](http://quadpoint.org/articles/irssi) - screen is another app which leaves a persistent session, multiple sessions running.  This way you can run screen and have irssi run within a screen session so you can close your terminal and irssi remains running.  Later if you want to open irssi back up you can reattach to your screen session.  I run my irssi/screen on my media server that way from my desktop or anywhere else I can ssh to my media server, attach to screen running irssi and its right there for you.
- [irssi themes](http://www.irssi.org/themes) - Need to find the one you like.  You can modify them easily too.
- [irssi scripts](http://scripts.irssi.org/) - There are some good ones here, depends on what you want to do though.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try all three...  So **irssi** ia a terminal app; interesting

Comment: see my updates for links.

Comment: A belated comment (approx 1 year later) I finally tried `irssi` seriously, and I now agree with you that `irssi` is the best client. I've chosen to use `tmux` instead of `screen`, but they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, mIRC [works fine in WINE](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20068), if you really need a mIRC script and can't be bothered to port it to some other client.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I came up with and that works very well is to just run VirtualBox. Install a nice clean version of Windows XP and install MiRC and it works wonders.